# Selenium Web driver: how do I click on image button without ID, NAME

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

Here is the image button source:

```html
<div class="btn">
    <a href="javascript:fncLogin();"><img src="/image/btn_login.jpg" alt="A_LOGIN"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@href='javascript:fncLogin();']").click()
```

You can use it's href.

If it's button class is unique you can do

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='btn']/a").click()
```